# Exit from parent process when child is running

Tags: c#, winforms, process

i have a WinForms application. And here is code from Form_Load method.

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\program files\MyProgram\start.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Application.ExecutablePath;
proc.Start();

Application.Exit();
```

Why is my parent process doesnt close program when i call Application.Exit? How to detect problem?

Comment: Because the application hasn't started yet when the Load event runs.  If makes very little sense to create a form and immediately want to terminate the app.  Just don't create the form.  Edit your Main() method in Program.cs

Comment: I'm trying to understand exactly what you are trying to achieve before giving a recomendation.  You have a windows forms application, that starts another process in the main form's load event?  Is this the only purpose of the parent WinForms application?

Answer (score 3):

Once you start a new process, its lifetime is independent of your current application’s. If you want an execution artefact that is directly tied to the lifetime of the current application, use threads.

If you’re sure you want to create a child process and then terminate it, you need to kill it:

```
Process proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\program files\MyProgram\start.exe";
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = Application.ExecutablePath;
proc.Start();

// When terminating:
proc.Kill();
proc.WaitForExit();
Application.Exit();
```

However, I wouldn’t recommend the above for most scenarios, since it can lead to data corruption if the child process is killed whilst performing a critical operation (such as saving to file).

Answer (score 0):

In order to exit a Windows Forms application, you should close the main form. Look at the code in Program.Main() and you'll see that what keeps the main thread alive is the main form. Close it and the application will exit.

Comment: Are you sure Form_Load gets called?

Comment: Yes, Form_load gets called. And start.exe and parent process is same program but i check execution path.